# What is the purpose of Allow External Data Under Excel Service Application --> External Data?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services

We have a excel book that we can open via excel web part on sharepoint page.

The excel book has external data connection to SQL Analysis server.

Presently the setting for Allow External Data is set to 'Trusted data connection libraries and embedded'. It shows up mthe excel book tables and the pivot chart and slicer.

Then, I tried to set Allow External Data to None; now also it displays all of the above. So what exactly is purpose of Allow External Data Under Excel Service Application --> External Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an added security layer in the excel service application that allows farm admins to grant users to upload and execute excel files in excel web viewer with embedded datasources connecting to different data providers (OLAP,OLEDB,etc.) . These datasources are external to the SharePoint farm and thereby needs additional authentication.

If you are showing data from OLAP cubes in your excel, excel services will also need you to configure kerberos authentication for your web application/unattended service account through secured store service application whichever applicable for DATA Refresh.

In short, excel services is tightly configurable from security standpoint. MS released a [data refresh flowchart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh369968%28v=office.14%29.aspx) which covers a lot of options that come into play in excel services including the one you have asked.

Comment: Hi Arko. Isn't the connection to the analysis db already stored in the excel file? Then why do we need secure store?